# element.select() doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I have a test where I go to Google.com and run the following commands in the console:

```
test = document.querySelector('#lst-ib') //#lst-ib is the ID of Google's search bar
test.value = 'abcd'
test.select()
window.getSelection().toString() //expected return value of 'abcd'
```

If I run this test in Chrome or Safari, I get the expected return value of 'abcd' - meaning the text in the input has been selected.

In FireFox, I get an empty string.

Does anyone have an explanation? I get the same behavior when I run this code on my own page from a script - not the console.

I'm testing on Firefox 54.01 and Chrome 59.0.3071.115

Comment: Why not just use `test.value`? Do you expect there to be any difference?

Comment: This is for a larger flow to roll my own Copy to Clipboard functionality.

Comment: Sure, but why use *select* and *getSelection* rather than just *value*, which is reliable and works everywhere?

Comment: Because `execCommand("copy")` will only work with the text that is highlighted on a page. You cannot pass it a value directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug for Firefox. 16 years and counting.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85686